# How do I keep the iTunes Video Window from resizing

Tags: itunes, video, podcasts

When watching videos or podcasts in a separate window in iTunes (10.4.1) OS X Snow Leopard, my preference is to place them at the bottom right of the screen. This is so I can keep browsing and working on other applications.
But when the next video starts, the window gets resized to the original size. How do I keep iTunes from doing this. 
FYI: The older version of iTunes did not exhibit this behavior. The window would remain in the user set size

Comment: I think this is no longer a problem—not sure since when, but I'm using 12.3.1 and it stays in the same position.